# Q binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$\sum^n_{j=0 }$ $q^{n^2}$ ${n\brack j}^2$ = ${2n\brack n}$

I have been trying a few things and working with the q binomial theorem but to no avail. I found the q-Vandermonde identity that looks similar to it but how does one work it around to prove the identity above?

Comment: Hi. I guess that is not well writen. If you take $q=1$, the identity is false.
It could possibly be $$\sum _{j=0}^n {n\brack j}_q^2q^{(n-j)^2}={2n \brack n}$$?

Comment: @Phicar, yes I had an error with the square of the bnomial on the left, but thats how it is written in my notes.

Comment: @Phicar Thanks btw!

Comment: Hi. That is a little bit better, but i think is false too. perhaps you have another typo
$$\sum^n_{j=0} q^{j^2} {n\brack j}^2 = {2n\brack n}$$

Comment: nope I am pretty sure I have it correctly taken down - I just asked a classmate. I have found other posts online mentioning it the way you have written it but unfortunately in German..http://homepage.univie.ac.at/johann.cigler/preprints/id1.pdf Possibly my teacher made a mistake.

Comment: It is indeed a mistake. Do it for $n=2$ and you will see. So, do it write an answer with the one i publish or you have Vandermonde's identity?

Comment: I dont understand that last comment? If you publish anything it will indeed help.

Comment: @Sean: Cigler’s notes simply say that it’s a special case of the $q$-Vandermonde identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that indeed you have a typo and you want to prove $$\sum _{i=0}^nq^{i^2}{n \brack i}^2={2n\brack n}.$$ Here is a combinatorial proof

Recall $${2n\brack n}=\sum _{i=0}^{n^2}A_{i,n,n}q^i,$$ where $A_{i,n,n}$ is the numbers of Ferrers Diagrams that can be embedded in the $n\times n$ square and that have area $i$. Then, you have a lot ($n^2$) of disjoint choices to embed a diagram in ${2n\brack n}$ as it is shown in the following picture.
[image]

So, If you increase $i$ between $0$ and $n$, you will have a diagram with an area greater or equal to $i^2$ by plugging a diagram to the right side (the diagram must be embedded in the $i \times (n-i)$ square) of the $i \times i$ square and to the bottom of it (the diagram must be embedded in the $(n-i)\times i$ square), and those are all the possibilities, so you have a way to partition all the Ferrers diagrams that are counted in ${2n\brack n}$ in blocks that counts diagrams which have an embedded $i\times i$ square by $q^{i^2}{n\brack i}^2$.

Hope it helps.